# Android : Error in getting id of any view created inside android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am not able to get Id of either Framelayout or Textview which are inside the toolbar. Please have a look :

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAppBg"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >
            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@+id/fl_message_bg"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:layout_gravity="right|center">
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/iv_cart"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/envelope"/>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tv_message_count"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
                        android:text="10"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        android:visibility="visible"
                        android:background="@drawable/circle_notification"/>
                </FrameLayout>            
            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

This is my code of finding ID of those view either in fragment or Activity which extends AppCompatActivity.
Inside Fragment :

```
`private Activity activity;
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        this.activity =(Activity)context;
    }
flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);`
```

In Activity :

FrameLayout flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);

I am getting null in both case.Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a support library so I you should set the toolbar as support action bar. Then you can get the views inside the toolbar by using **toolbar.findviewbyid(id)**

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
ImageView iv = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.iv_cart);
```

if you're using a fragment and your activity extends **AppCompatActivity** then you can set the support action bar as follows:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Comment: @Malek Thanks. I tried your solution but still getting this `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference`

Comment: @Harry did you set your toolbar as suppurt action bar?

Comment: @Harry dont forget to replace the R.id.chat_toolbar with the id of your toolbar which is R.id.toolbar

Comment: @Harry I edited the answer and changed it to R.id.toolbar

Comment: @Malek. Got it. I have created three layout folder **layout,layout-large-port and layout-xlarge-port** and I miss to change the ID while I am testing for Tablet which pick Id from **layout-large-port**. Thanks again for same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
FrameLayout flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your sollution but I am still getting **null** for FrameLayout **flMessageCountBg**. Inside my Activity which extends AppCompatActivity.

Comment: And place this code inside onCreate method of Activity

Comment: Still getting **null** 

   ` public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_common, container, false);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
                FrameLayout flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);
System.out.println("flMessageCountBg toolbar : +flMessageCountBg);
getIds();  return view; }'

Answer (score 1):

Get your **toolbar** from your **activity** in the **fragment** then you get your **framelayout** from your **toolbar** like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
FrameLayout flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this but I am still getting **null** for Framelayout **flMessageCountBg**.

Comment: Thanks done it in fragment using this `flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was very simple of getting id (Inside Fragment) of view created within android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar. 
`flMessageCountBg = (FrameLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fl_message_bg);`

I have created three layout folder **layout,layout-large-port and layout-xlarge-port** and I miss to change the ID while I am testing for 7 inch Tablet which pick Id from layout-large-port.

> @Malek,@Context and @bhargav

Thanks for your help.